# Axis2 deployment issues

Tags: apache, apache-axis

i have installed apache and tomcat6 .. i have downloaded and installed axis2 1.5.4 .. now when i go the services list and click on the default service version i got this error ..

> The endpoint reference (EPR) for the
>   Operation not found is
>   /axis2/services/Version and the WSA
>   Action = null

i have installed axis2 on Mac there was no problem .. i have installed axis2 previously on windows and there was no issues also .. i dont know why this time it is acting like that

appreciate any help
regards

Comment: What webservices do you have installed inside that Axis2 installation?

Comment: currently none !! but whenever i install a service i get the same error .. i have installed services that have been tested previously and working .. now when i simply want to click on version .. the service already installed i get this error ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the solution was rather very strange .. there was no problem in the web service itself .. but apparently firefox or chrome could not view the wsdl file .. when viewing the page with IE it worked and showed the .wsdl file